# What values can the given determinant not take under the given conditions?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let A & B are two $n\space \times \space n$ matrices with real entries and $|B|\ne0$ then:

> 1. $|A^2+I_n|$ can not be?
>    (a) -1
>    (b) 1
>    (c) 2
>    (d) 0
> 2. |$I_n-AB|-|I_n-BA|$ is equal to?
>    (a) 0
>    (b) 1
>    (c) 2
>    (d) 5

Where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of order n.

---

I am not able to get to a rigid approach/method that would help to solve these problems. Since $|B|\ne0$ was the only major condition I found useful in the given data,

My Teacher gave me this hint and I tried looking at a few cases about A and B which might help solve the Second problem, But I still couldn't reach the answer.

Here's what I did:

Let's say $$BA=O \implies |BA|=0 \implies |B||A|=0\implies |A|=0 \space or \space |B|=0$$
where $O$ is the null matrix
given, $|B|\ne0$ which means it's inverse would exist.

Hence,  $$B^{-1}BA=B^{-1}O \implies A=O$$

This means that if the product of two matrices is the null matrix, and if one of them is non singular, then the other must be a null matrix.

We can also conclude that if both are not null matrices, then the Determinants of each would be 0.

---

This approach seems to be a bit vague as there's no necessity for BA to be equal to the null matrix in the first place. The first problem seems to be intuitive and I can't reach it's solution as well. It would be great if someone could help me out!

(I am a high school student and don't have any idea about 'Eigenvalues or eigenvectors' I am just mentioning this as I have seen these terms being used in a lot of Matrix related problems on this site. I would appreciate an explanation in elementary and basic terms.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First question :** The correct answer is **a)**. Indeed, one has
\begin{align*}\det(I + A^2) &= \det ((I + iA)(I - iA))\\
& = \det(I + iA) \det(I - iA)\\
&= \det(I + iA)\det(\overline{I + iA)} \\
&= \det(I + iA) \overline{\det(I + iA)} \ge 0
\end{align*}

Moreover, both options **b), c)** and **d)** are incorrect, since you have the following respective counterexamples :
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \text{and} \quad\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

**Second question :** The answer is **a)**. Indeed
$$\det (I - AB) = \det \left[B^{-1}(I - BA)B\right] = (\det B^{-1}) \det(I - BA)\det(B) = \det (I - BA)$$

so $\det (I - AB) - \det (I - BA) = 0$. And this also shows that the other options are not correct.

Comment: That was rather a very simple and straight solution. Thanks! Also, can you please provide a source/place where I can know about the property you used in the first question ( I believe it's related to conjugate of Complex numbers ) as I was not familiar to it before.

Comment: I just used two facts about complex conjugacy : the fact that $\overline{a+ib}=a-ib$ if $a,b$ are reals (this is the point where I use that $A$ is a real matrix), and the fact that $\overline{\det(M)}=\det(\overline{M})$, which is quite immediate since the determinant is polynomial w.r.t. the coefficients of a matrix.